# Dynamic running header with flying-saucer

Tags: java, html, css, flying-saucer

I have been using flying-saucer for my PDF generator service.

I am correctly using css @Page rules for adding running headers and footers on each page

```
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    margin: 10%;
    @top-left { content: element(header); }
    @bottom-left { content: element(footer); }
}

header {
    position: running(header);
}

footer{
    position: running(footer);
}
```

---

***Question***

My HTML and generated PDF contains below sections (just as an example)

1. Career Objective
2. Summary
3. Qualification
4. Employment History
5. Project Experience

where:

- Each Section starts on a new page.
- No two sections on same page.
- Depending on content each section may/may not occupy multiple pages

My requirement is to have header on each page displaying the section name the page contains.

E.g. if project experience occupy two pages then both of the page headers should contain word `Project Experience`

Can anyone point me to a possible solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to crack it down and it was rather simpler than I was expecting.

---

> Answer is to create multiple  tags (one per section) instead
>   of having one common header for the entire report. Mark *postition*
>   each header as *running* and that's it. Flying-saucer will do its job

.

**For example**

*My CSS is still the same (as it is in question)*

```
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    margin: 10%;
    @top-left { content: element(header); }
}

header {
    position: running(header);
}
```

I just refactored my HTML

```
<div class="page">
    <header>Section 1 / My Fancy Report</header>
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <!-- Section 1 content --> 
</div>
<div class="page">
    <header>Section 2 / My Fancy Report</header>
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <!-- Section 2 content --> 
</div>
```

If any of the section here overflows to the next page flying-saucer correctly repeats the sectional header on next page.

Hope it helps others.

Comment: Hi Amit, my table content goes to the next page, I manage to repeat the header but when table size extends more then single page the footer is not getting printed. Any clue how do we make sure the footer is also printed when table size exceeds to the next page?

Comment: @ParthKansara I think it is unrelated to the question on this page. Feel free to put it as a separate question on Stackoverflow.